# Hypergraph terminology question

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading a paper ("Hall's theorem for Hypergraphs" by Aharoni and Haxell), and got stuck with the terminology appearing in the third sentence(!)

The first three sentences are:
A hypergraph is a set of subsets, called edges, of some ground set. A matching in
the hypergraph is a set of disjoint edges. We say that a set F of edges is pinned by
another set K of edges if every edge in F is *met* by some edge from K.

My question is what does it mean for one hyperedge to meet another? Do they have to be equal? Do they just have to have some vertices in common?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Usually, two sets $X$ and $Y$ are said to *meet* if $X\cap Y\ne\varnothing$. I don't know if "meet" has a special meaning in hypergraph theory. I very much doubt that it means they have to be **equal**; if every edge in $F$ is **equal** to some edge from $K$, they could have just said $F\subseteq K$.

Comment: @bof: Thanks. Sounds right. I guess in spite of the first sentence, I just don’t think of edges in graphs as sets, and am feeling around for a geometric picture of the hyperedges too.

Comment: The vertices and edges of a hypergraph could, for example, be the points and lines of a finite geometry. Two lines meet if they have a point in common.

Comment: Thanks @bof: I totally agree that in the example you're describing, "meet" seems like a very natural word to use.